# How filter & format a json in node.js?

Tags: node.js, json

I want to format a JSON object in my Nodejs server. Delete some fields, rename some fields, and move some fields.

I have many different schemas need to apply to many different JSON, so I hope has a lib that can parse a configuration file and to it.

Maybe a configuration file like this:

```
DELETE request.logid
DELETE request.data.*.time
MOVE request.data.images data.images
```

And a JSON before applies an above schema:

```
{
  "request": {
    "data": {
      "book": {
        "name": "Hello World",
        "time": 1546269044490
      },
      "images": [
        "a-book.jpg"
      ]
    },
    "logid": "a514-afe1f0a2ac02_DCSix"
  }
}
```

After applied:

```
{
  "request": {
    "data": {
      "book": {
        "name": "Hello World"
      }
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "images": [
      "a-book.jpg"
    ]
  }
}
```

Where is the lib it is?

I know that write a function can do the same thing directly, but the problem is I have too many different schemas and too many different JSON, so I wanna manage them by configuration file rather than a js function.

Comment: Can you explain little bit more. If you want to update a json format, write a custom function so that the json can be altered.

Comment: @Muhammedshah I have updated the question. I know that write a function can do the same thing directly, but the problem is I have too many different schemas and too many different JSON, so I wanna manage them by configuration file rather than a js function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could do something like this...

```
// Note: psuedocode
// Read the configuration file;
const commands = (await readFile('config')).split('\r\n').split(' ');
// your original JSON;
const obj = {...};
// Modify the JSON given the commands
commands.forEach( row=>{
  if(row[0]==="DELETE"){
    delete obj[row[1]];
  }else if(row[0]==="MOVE"){
    // use lodash to make your life easier. 
    _.set(obj,`${row[2]}`,_.get(obj,`${row[1]}`));
    delete obj[row[1]];
  }else if(...){
    ...
  }
})
```